# Mulitple sheets combine into one sheets with alternative columns

Tags: excel

I have 6 different excel sheets with different data from stocks,

```
1-first sheet: weekly average price of 88 stocks(AAPL, GOOG,MFST,etc.)


2-second sheet: weekly average highest price of 88 stocks(AAPL, GOOG,MFST,etc.)


3-third sheet: weekly deviation of 88 stocks(AAPL, GOOG,MFST,etc.)


4-forth sheet: weekly volume of 88 stocks(AAPL, GOOG,MFST,etc.)


5-fifth sheet: weekly sharpe of 88 stocks(AAPL, GOOG,MFST,etc.)


6-sixth sheet: weekly return of 88 stocks(AAPL, GOOG,MFST,etc.)
```

**I  want to combine 6 sheets into one sheet with columns A to F for AAPL, and then columns G to L for GOOG, so on .......**

How can I do it simply?

Thanks!

Comment: Upload sample of the data from each sheet and the output you want

Comment: If your range is static (i.e. columns and rows that you need to pick up from each sheet) then you could do this with just formulas. If not, you may need VBA code

Comment: i prefer to do this with formulas, but i failed to do it